# What is wrong with the code because of which i am getting no output in browser though my code is compiled properly?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

To install reactJs i used [docs given by facebook](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html) . And now i am trying to  implement routing using but nothing is getting displayed in my browser.
**And one more thing i I want to ask where is config file according to this docs.**

*Package.json file*

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

*Index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router'
import {App} from "./App";
import {About} from "./about";
import {Contact} from "./contactus";
import {Home} from "./Home"


ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
         <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path={"home"} component={Home} />
            <Route path={"about"} component={About} />
            <Route path={"contact"} component={Contact} />
         </Route>
      </Router>,

  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

***App.js***

```
import React from 'react';

import  Link from 'react-router'
import Home from './Home'
import About from './about'
import Contact from './contactus'

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
               <li><Link to="/home"><Home /></Link></li>
               <li><Link to="/about"><About /></Link></li>
               <li><Link to="/contact"><Contact /></Link></li>
            </ul>


         </div>
      )
   }
}




export default App;
```

***about.js***

```
import React from 'react';



class About extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>About...</h1>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default About;
```

In the same way i have defined contact.js and home.js.

Error on thr browser looks like

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check your code at index.js:13.
printWarning @ warning.js:35
warning.js:35 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Router (at index.js:11)
printWarning @ warning.js:35
Router.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
    at new Router (Router.js:47)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:294
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:293)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:279)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:187)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
```

[here is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ceK.png)

*And my output is blank in browser.
ps:i am beginner with ReactJs so dont get offended with poor coding structure*

Comment: Whats your project structure and do you have a `contactus.js` file?

Comment: `Cannot read property 'location' of undefined` means one of your component is missing. And react-router can't find it.

Comment: my project structure is: under my-app i have public and src folder, inside public i have index.html and inside src i have about.js,App.js,contactus.js,Home.js and index.js

Comment: By looking at the first error message (`expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function...`) it looks like you are importing one of your components wrongly.

Comment: `You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check your code at index.js:13`

Comment: @HanaAlaydrus  i have included image of my file structure as well, can u do something for me pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you use react-router v4. Turns out in v4 `browserHistory, IndexRoute` is no longer exist in v4. And use `react-router-dom` not `react-router`

My suggestion is to change to this code.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import App from "./App";
import About from "./about";
import Contact from "./contactus";
import Home from "./Home"

const customHistory = createBrowserHistory()

class MainApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
    <Router history={customHistory}>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    </Router>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainApp />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And in App.js between `<link>Text</link>` you need text not component

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <div>
              <ul>
                <li><Link to="/home">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
         <Router>
      )
   }
}

export default App;
```

There are many example of react-router v4 here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Answer (score 0):

Your About component is exported as default, so when you want to import it you need this:

```
import About from './about'
```

instead of

```
import {About} from './about'
```

It's a subtle and annoying problem :)

Comment: sir i have included image of my file structure, can you please solve my issue?